# How to disable caching for a custom PIP in TSPM?

Tags: java, xacml

I'm using IBM's Tivoli Security Policy Manager with a custom PIP (implementing `com.ibm.tscc.rtss.authz.api.IExternalFinder`). I can see my PIP from TIP console, and I'm able to configure it to provide values for parameters in my policies. However, when those policies are evaluated as a result of an authorization request, my PIP is only asked to provide a value every couple of minutes or so. The old value is used in the mean time.

To demonstrate this, my PIP has an internal state consisting of an `int counter` which is increased by one on calls to the `get*Attributes` methods. The single `String` type (environment) attribute produced by my PIP indicates `"even"` or `"odd"` depending on the value of `counter % 2`. I was expecting that the user was granted access every other attempt, but this is not what happens if requests are sent too soon after each other.

Is there a way to force TSPM not to cache results from my PIP? Where is this configured in TSPM or WebSphere?

Comment: The timeout appears to be 120 seconds.

Comment: BTW, right after the first authorization attempt the system log show a CWRGS1139E, complaining that the system property specifying the home directory was not found. Various values for `commonauthz.home` make this error go away (but don't solve my problem).

Comment: Setting in `DisableCaching` to `true` (it was `false`) in `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/config/tspm/xacml/config.xml` doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no caching for PIPs in the current release of TSPM... only request / response caching.  It definitely sounds like this is what's happening - the default timeout is indeed 120 seconds.  Please revert all your configuration changes to default: don't set anything for commonauthz.home - it's a red herring; and revert your config.xml changes to default.

The correct place to disable request / response caching is in the file `<PROFILE_HOME>/config/<CELL>/rtss/security-services.xmi`.  Add or edit this section:

```
<components name="Authz">
      <subComponents name="AuthzServices">
        <items name="CommonAuthz">
          <properties>
            <values name="com.ibm.sec.authz.xacml.runtime.DisableCaching" value="true" type="java.lang.String"/>
           </properties>
        </items>
      </subComponents>
```

Then restart RTSS.

I wouldn't recommend this in a production environment though.